# Can shopify ScriptTag do that?

Tags: shopify

I considering integrating Shopify platform with third party loyalty/rewards provider. 
For that I need to be able to allow customer to redeem his points at the moment of purchase.
This will involve adding extra control to Shopping cart, such as button [Redeem your points]

Can I use ScriptTag injection to:

1. Access information about currently logged on customer (customer email) ?
2. Modify current shopping cart total and have customer to pay less than total (let him apply loyalty points)?

Answer (score 1):

Arbitrarily modifying the cost of a cart/order is not possible. Based on this restriction, I do not recommend trying to integrate/implement points card functionality.